# How to add a string to a number

Tags: bash, scripts

I have been recently trying to create a script that can convert a binary number to a decimal. This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Specify no of digits"
read digits

if [[ $digits == 1 ]]; then
        echo "Enter 1 st digit"
        read 1
elif [[ $digits == 2 ]]; then
        echo "Enter 1 st digit"
        read 1
        echo "Enter 2 nd digit"
        read 2
elif [[ $digits == 3 ]]; then
        echo "Enter 1 st digit"
        read 1
        echo "Enter 2 nd digit"
        read 2
        echo "Enter 3 rd digit"
        read 3
elif [[ $digits > 3 ]]; then
        echo "Enter 1 st digit"
        read 1
        echo "Enter 2 nd digit"
        read 2
        echo "Enter 3 rd digit"
        read 3
        for digitno in {4..$digits};
        do
                echo "Enter $digitno th digit"
                read $digitno
                ($nodigits++)
        done
echo "$4"
else
        echo "Please enter a valid no of digits. Type './binary_decoder.sh'"
        exit 1
fi
```

It's a pretty long script, I know. But please try and take the time to examine this script.

If you look at any of the `read` lines inside the if conditional, you will see that the variables to which the `read` statements are assigning the numbers to are themselves numbers. With Bash syntax, that will not work. I want for the variables to be like n1, n2, n3, n4... and so on. But, if you see inside the `elif [[ $digits > 3 ]]; then` statement, you can see that there is a for loop that allows for an infinite no of digits to be decoded. Now, I do not know any way to add the string `n` to the number in the variable `$digitno`. But I was wondering that if any of you can maybe figure out how to add the string `n` to the `$digitno` variable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Google for "bash arrays".

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu question, it belongs on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @pzkpfw bash scripting is on topic here

Answer (score 1):

You can add a string to a number using simple concatenation:

```
$ i=3
$ echo n$i
n3
```

however that doesn't help much with your real goal here, which seems to be *how to assign an indeterminate number of user inputs to indexed variables*.

As you've already discovered, you can't use variables named `1`, `2`, `3` etc. in a `read` command. Aside from the fact that bash variable names must at least *begin* with an alphabetic character or an underscore, the expansions `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on are reserved for the shell's *positional parameters*.

If you really want to use `$1` ... `$n` in your script, you can actually do so using the `set` shell builtin. Note that whereas POSIX only requires support for parameters up to `$9`, bash supports an arbitrary number (although for indexes above 9 you will need to use braces to disambiguate between, for example, `${10}` as the 10<sup>th</sup> positional parameter and `$10` as the concatenation of `$1` with literal `0`). For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set --
while : ; do
  read -n1
  case $REPLY in
    [01]) set -- "$@" "$REPLY"
    ;;
    *) break
    ;;
  esac
done

for ((i=1; i<=$#; ++i)); do
  printf 'Digit #%d = %d\n' "$i"  "${!i}"
done
```

The user enters a sequence of `0` and `1` characters, terminating the sequence by hitting any other character (including newline):

```
$ ./bin2dec
1011010110
Digit #1 = 1
Digit #2 = 0
Digit #3 = 1
Digit #4 = 1
Digit #5 = 0
Digit #6 = 1
Digit #7 = 0
Digit #8 = 1
Digit #9 = 1
Digit #10 = 0
```

Alternatively, you could do essentially the same with a user-defined array:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=()
while : ; do
  read -n1
  case $REPLY in
    [01]) arr+=("$REPLY")
    ;;
    *) break
    ;;
  esac
done

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; ++i)); do
  printf 'Digit #%d = %d\n' "$i"  "${arr[i]}"
done
```

Note the different indexing; although both arrays are zero-based, the zeroth element of `$@` is reserved for the name of the script file.

Comment: My 'Real goal' actually isn't to assign a variable with the name as a number. If you look at the code that i uploaded, you can see that i am trying to use a for loop that can make and assign different values and names an infinite number of times. So I was hoping that i could make a code that could add a string to a number some thing like this: `read ["n" + $x]` and if x's value was 1, it would assign the user inputed value to the variable n1 and so on and forth.